# Specifiying escape characters when importing into BigQuery. "Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator."

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to import a large amount of .csv files into Google BigQuery.

One of my String columns sometimes contains an array which contains double quotes that are escaped with `\`'s. Example:

...`,"{\"ex1\":\"somestuffhere\"\,\"ex2\":\"somestuffhere\"\,\"ex3\":\"somestuffhere\"}",`...

I believe the issue is caused by BigQuery by default expecting double quotes to be escaped with another double quote - `""`. I have experimented sending different parameters to the `--quote` argument but it does not function as I was hoping.

The current command line load command I am attempting:

`bq load --noreplace --skip_leading_rows=1 --allow_jagged_rows='true' --ignore_unknown_values='true' --quote='"' --source_format=CSV TestDataset.cmdLineTest gs://s3_data_transfers/Events_10422/LIVE/* myschema.json`

Is there anyway I can get the platform to accept these rows? Or am I forced to investigate preprocessing steps? This table will be updated every day based on new csv's being sent, so ideally trying to keep preprocessing steps to a minimum.

Thanks!

Comment: I never found a solution for this. I ended up importing the entire dataset as a s single column string table and then handling it from there using REGEX.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is due to `--quote` argument that you have already pointed out. Since `"` is the default value to quote CSV data sections, it is incoherent if your data contains `"`. I have been testing with some similar data (with `\"`) and BigQuery returns the same error:

```
Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator.
```

The solution for this is to specify the `--quote` flag to another character (in this way, the incoherence will be solved). In my case, it worked with `'`. The following command worked for me:

```
bq --location=US load --autodetect --source_format=CSV --quote "'" MY_DATASET.MY_TABLE MY_CSV_FILE
```

Make sure that your data does not contain `'`, Otherwise you should find another character for that or set it to empty string as documentation states. Refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) for details about this flag.

Comment: This would work, however because many of my columns do contain data that is wrapped by `"` it means they can only be processed as Strings. Sadly this ruins partitioning and other features that are required on this much data on things like timestamp columns.

Example error:
`starting at location 4901
- query: Could not parse '\"2018-11-22 00:00:00.0\"' as a timestamp.
Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]; Could not parse
'"2018-11-22 00:00:00.0"' as datetime for field eventDate (position`...

Comment: I have been testing with this. `\"2018-11-22 00:00:00.0\"` will be detect as `STRING` if using `--autodetect` and will raise your error if provide the schema. I think you should preprocess your data or import it into BigQuery as `STRING`, then remove the `\"` and convert it to the proper data type.

Comment: Ah the `\\`'s are only in the command line output they aren't actually in my data (for the date issue, they are for the arrays in original question). Autodetect cannot handle my data due to the array having commas in also.
I think my choices are either to preprocess, or import the entire dataset as a 1 column string and then handle from there.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding --quote "" in the command line resolved the error for me.